# NSURLConnection delegate gets connectionDidFinishLoading only once after 15 rapid calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I create 15 rapid requests using `NSURLConnection`

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:url delegate:callback];
[conn start];
```

The server receives all 15 requests and provides the appropriate response. But my delegate object receives only a single `connectionDidFinishLoading:` method call.

What could be the underlying cause?

Comment: Couldn't it be that only your last `callback` object is being initialized and you're getting a response just for the last call?

Comment: @SergiusGee I checked this by reimplementing the `init` method with a `NSLog` and I see 15 calls to init. So I guess this isn't it.

Comment: And when you put, say, a 1-2 second delay between the calls, it all works fine?

Comment: This is part of Xcode unit testing, so I can't really put in a delay in each test.

Comment: Are you running this on the main thread? If you aren't, it's possible that the thread exits before the delegate methods get called. Have you implemented the other delegate methods to see if you are getting the 15 calls anywhere else?

Comment: Are you sure your delegate doesn't get released after the first one?

Comment: BTW, you are starting this connection twice. The `initWithRequest:delegate:` method starts the connection automatically. Only use `start` method if you use `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` and supplying `NO` for `startImmediately`. This second `start` can actually cause problems, so definitely remove it unless you use `startImmediately` of `NO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the NSURLConnection on the main run loop:

```
NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] 
                            initWithRequest:request
                                   delegate:callback 
                           startImmediately:NO];

[connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] 
                      forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[connection start];
```

Also, when using:

```
 [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:url delegate:callback];
```

You don't need to call `start` as the connection has already been started. `start` is only needed when using `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` and passed `NO` to `startImmediately`.

Comment: Thanks for showing a new workflow for dealing with `NSURLConnection`. But the result is the same.